# How to identify the original manufacturer of lenses branded Focal (Kmart)?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, vintage

There are Focal-branded lenses for which I wish to identify the manufacturer.

I have read that Focal is the Kmart house brand for optical equipment (cameras, lenses, binoculars, etc). They also appear to have encoded the manufacturer in the serial number, so in principle, I just need to find a list of applicable manufacturer codes. I have so-far been unable to find such a list.

What are the manufacturer codes for lenses that have been rebranded Focal (Kmart)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is not complete. It will be updated as I obtain more information. Feel free to edit or comment if you have relevant information to add.*

Focal appears to have used multiple systems to identify their lenses.

- Some lenses have serial numbers with a **letter-code prefix**.

  - **C = Cimko**? Another supporting characteristic would be the presence of a diamond outline reference mark for the distance and aperture scales.
  - **H = Tokina**? The same letter code appears to have used on multiple rebranded lenses. For instance, consider this set:

    [image: Tokina 35/2.8]
    [image: Super-Focal 35/2.8]
    [image: Super-Lentar 35/2.8]

    However, there's [speculation](http://forum.mflenses.com/soligor-12-8-f28mm-21and-versions-t30866,highlight,soligor++28mm,start,25.html) that **H = Hoya**, who then subcontracted with various manufacturers, such as Sun, Komine, and Tokina.
- Some lenses have what appears to be a **model number**, which consists of three sets of two-digit numbers. This number is often printed on a sticker on the side of the barrel.

**Links:**

- All Photo Lenses: [Tokina 35mm f/2.8 Wide-Auto Lens](http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_3468.html)
- M42 Lens: [Focal Auto Super-Focal 35mm f/2.8-16](http://m42lens.com/m42-lens-database/980-focal-auto-super-focal-35mm-f-2-8-16)